# Text comparison - find any common group of n words without knowing the words beforehand

Tags: python

Suppose I have two text files, `Test` and `Master`, each of varying length. I want to parse through `Test` to see if it has any n consecutive words in common with `Master`.

For example, if n = 5, return a list that has as its elements five word phrases that are common between `Test` and `Master`. For example, one of the elements would be `and then we went to`, if this grouping of five words existed in both files.

I have no idea if libraries exist for this, they probably do, but I'm unaware of them. As far my own solution, one popped into my head where I might split both files on whitespace and iterate through them to see if elements 0 through 4 match, then 1 through 5, 2 through 6, etc. Seems very inefficient, especially with larger files.

Any advice is appreciated, and if I can expand further on the question, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: So this is some sort of *plagiarism* detection tool? Looks to me you can use `diff` for that.

Comment: I guess it could be used for that, but this is just part of personal project for me. In fact, I really only need to find the *first* match of n consecutive words to proceed. What is `diff`? `difflib`?

Comment: I would build a set of all five-word groups in `Test` (concatenated into a string) and another set for `Master`, and then take the intersect of the sets.